# Enable / disable functionalities for users on Ms Teams custom App

Tags: microsoft-teams, custom-application

I'm planning to build a custom application for Ms Teams and I wanted the app to have an 'Administration' context, reserved for some users, with charts and records management that the rest of the users wouldn't be able to see. Is there a way to accomplish this?
Is it possible to hide tabs depending on a user profile? Is there another way to accomplish this on teams?

Tks

Answer (score 1):

Inside your tab you can do whatever you want - it's just a custom web app/page. The only "restriction" aside from a normal web app, is that it must implement the Teams javascript library - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context) for more. However, once you've implemented that library, you can get the Teams context, which includes the user's Azure AD Id and also UPN, and you could use one or both of those to do a lookup against your database, determine the user's role, and show/hide UI elements accordingly.

However, I think you might be asking about whether the entire Tab -itself- (i.e. even the tab item inside the Teams client) can be hidden from other users. To do this, an option is to use a "private channel", just for the relevant users, and pin the tab inside there only.